# How to Serialize Complex Object to JSON in python

Tags: python, django

I have complex object that composite list of other objects.
I will serialize this object to JSON value to perform creation an viewModel.

```
class refereereport(Model):
    competition = models.ForeignKey(competition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reportdate = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    reporttime = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    reviewerreferee = models.ForeignKey(reviewer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    federationdeletage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    longdescriptions = models.TextField()
    isdelete = models.BooleanField()

class competitionreferee(Model):
    competitionkey = models.ForeignKey(competition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    referee = models.ForeignKey(referee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=refereemebers)
```

Comment: Luckily they documented exactly that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/